# data binding issue on socket.on

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I am working on chat application and mentioned issue below.
**Issue:**

1. This is ont to one communication process.
2. From A message sending to B
3. Both A and B are connected in the same room and message displaying for Both.
   4) Once A message sends to  From Angular4(socket.io-client) request goes to NodeJs (socket.in). then Node js responding with the Message and logged in user id(User A uniquer id) to the sender.
4. Now The in angular4 I unable to bind the variable value inside the socket.on function. and returns undefined.

**Node js code:**

```
socket.on("sendMessage", (data) => {
    console.log(data.msg + "..." + data.to);
    socket.username = data.by;
    io.to(data.to).emit("msgReceived", { "msg": data.msg, "by": socket.username });     //response back to client
});

socket.on("joinRoom", (data) => {
    socket.join(data.sid);
    console.log('You have joined in ' + data.sid + ' room');
    ......
```

**Client side code:**

```
/* Passing value to the server */
isMessageSent() {
    this.socket.emit('sendMessage', { "msg": this.umsg, "to": '123', "by": this.lgid, "lguser": this.lgid });
    this.socket.on("msgReceived", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    /* Response from the serve */
    this.socket.on("msgReceived", function (data) {

        console.log(data.by + "...." + this.lguser);
        if (data.by == this.lguser) {
            $("#chul").append("<li class='clr'> <p _ngcontent-c1 class='fu fl'>" + data.msg + "</p></li>");
        } else {
            $("#chul").append("<li class='clr'> <p _ngcontent-c1 class='fd fr'>" + data.msg + "</p></li>");
        }
        .....
```

Comment: **Now The in angular4 I unable to bind the variable value inside the socket.on function. and returns undefined.**

what do you mean by this? wchich variable?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara  I have private lguser;  in component which has the cookie value (logged in user unique id), I want to check that value in the socket.on  like if(this.lguser == data.sid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. you have to bind the context. Read more about context binding in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

I have create a separate function to handle the event. And I am uing `bind` method to bind the context.

`this.handleMessageReceivedEvent.bind(this)`

---

Your code should look like this.

```
    this.socket.on("msgReceived", this.handleMessageReceivedEvent.bind(this));

    private handleMessageReceivedEvent(): void {
        console.log(data.by+"...."+this.lguser);
        if(data.by==this.lguser){
           $("#chul").append("<li class='clr'> <p _ngcontent-c1 class='fu fl'>"+data.msg+"</p></li>");
        }else{
           $("#chul").append("<li class='clr'> <p _ngcontent-c1 class='fd fr'>"+data.msg+"</p></li>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Auratha Gunasekaran, you have saved my time. :)

Comment: Sorry Buddy, I Unable to upvote for you since i have less than 15 reputation.